# Issue calling time series data by date

Tags: python, csv, pandas

So I have been working with the following data:

```
      Date  AB1  BC1 MB1 NWT1 SK1 Total1  AB2 BC2 MB2 SK2 Total2
0   2007-01-05  305   76   1    0  36    418  324  64   0  23    417
1   2007-01-12  427   95   5    0  58    585  435  82   2  62    586
2   2007-01-19  481  102   4    0  65    652  460  77   3  63    606
3   2007-01-26  491   98   6    0  59    654  506  79   4  70    664
4   2007-02-02  459   95   6    2  55    617  503  79   5  71    660
5   2007-02-09  459   88   5    4  61    617  493  73   4  68    641
6   2007-02-16  450   83   5    5  60    603  486  74   5  68    636
....
```

And using the following code to read the data, parse it and now trying to call it by 'sdate'.

```
def readcsv3():
    csv_data = read_csv(file3,dtype=object,parse_dates=[0])
    csv_data3 = csv_data.values
    return csv_data3

def otherrigs():
    sdate='2007-01-26'
    df = readcsv3()
    df = DataFrame(df,columns=['Date','AB1','BC1','MB1','NWT1','SK1','Total1','AB2','BC2','MB2','SK2','Total2'])


    print(df[sdate])
```

Now I get the following error:

KeyError: '2007-01-26'

Process finished with exit code 1

Any suggestions?

Comment: you should not pass ``dtype=object`` in ``read_csv``. ``read_csv`` will figure out the dtypes correctly (and you never want ``object`` on non-strings anyhow)

Comment: what does dtype=object change the data type to?

Comment: and also, I have this: csv_data.values in there. What does that do?

Comment: it would coerce to ``object`` dtype, which is only for string-likes (but this is inferred anyhow). You should only specify ``dtype=...`` if you have a really good reason (e.g. you have integers but you want them as string-like, say they are an identifier or something)

Comment: Ok cool good to know, thanks. Not a programmer by trade so picking things up now and again.

Comment: np. docs are really good, and their are many examples of how to do things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks you are trying to access the row containing '2007-01-26', but your syntax is trying to pull a column name. Try

```
print(df[df['Date'] == sdate])
```

As an aside, you might also look at the pandas pd.read_csv() function, it will get those column names for you.

Comment: Question with the solution, is there a way to just reference it directly. Like df[sdate] which would have the entire dataframe indexed by the dates?